# How to make Plot Face non-transparent in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb4XM.png)

I'm attempting to plot some data in matplotlib, and I cannot figure out how to get the plot to save without transparency on the 'face' behind the x and y axis labels.

Here's my code:

````
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 40})
plt.plot(f_hours_BEST,BEST_data, marker = hurricane_svg, markersize=50, color = 'r', label='BEST')
plt.plot(f_hours_OFCL,OFCL_data, marker = hurricane_svg, markersize=50, label = 'OFCL')
plt.boxplot(Vlist, widths=5, positions = f_hours_EPS)
plt.title("EPS Ensemble Intensity vs BEST and OFCL forecast AL31 2020-11-14 12z")
plt.xlabel("Forecast Hour")
plt.ylabel("Intensity (kts)")
plt.legend()

plt.savefig('EPS.png')```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `transparent=False` to `plt.savefig` or setting a `facecolor`/`edgecolor`.

Source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

PS: The `EPS.png` that I generated had already white background, but maybe it's because of my default backend.